# How to allow users to only update certain fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this store procedure and I lets assume the user want to update some fields not all of it, what should I add on the update section

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[helpChainAllCRUD] 
    @action char(1),
    @lineId char(2),
    @lineShift smallint = NULL, 
    @sequence smallint = NULL,
    @Role VARCHAR(32) = NULL,
    @radioChannel VARCHAR(16)= NULL,
    @officePhone VARCHAR(16)= NULL,
    @cellPhone VARCHAR(16)= NULL
as

IF(@action = 'I')
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_helpChain] (lineId,lineShift,sequence,Role,radioChannel,officePhone,cellPhone)
            VALUES (@lineId ,@lineShift,@sequence,@Role,@radioChannel,@officePhone,@cellPhone)
        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT >0
            ROLLBACK
    END CATCH

IF(@action = 'U')
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
            UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_helpChain] SET lineShift=@lineShift,sequence=@sequence,Role=@Role,radioChannel=@radioChannel,officePhone=@officePhone,cellPhone=@cellPhone WHERE lineId=@lineId
            COMMIT
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT >0
            ROLLBACK
    END CATCH

IF(@action = 'D')
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
        Delete from [dbo].[tbl_helpChain] WHERE lineId=@lineId
        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT >0
            ROLLBACK
    END CATCH

IF(@action = 'S')
    Begin
        select lineId,lineShift,sequence,Role,radioChannel,officePhone,cellPhone from [dbo].[tbl_helpChain]  
    end

GO
```

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

If i.e. null means don't update you could simply write

```
SET lineShift = COALESCE(@lineShift,lineShift), ...
```

or you take another special value and a case-expression

```
SET lineShift = CASE WHEN @lineShift = -1 then lineShift else @lineShift end,
```

or you give extra boolean parameters for each column for use in the case-expression

Comment: I appreciate your response, I figured it out in another way too, you can take a look at it also. This one for some reason didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are much better solutions, but a quick and easy solution might be to use very ugly dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @QueryText nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_helpChain] SET '

IF @radioChannel<> NULL
@QueryText = @QueryText + 'RadioChannel=@radioChannel'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @QueryText
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, I figured it out in another way too, you can take a look at it also. This one for some reason didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE helpChain

SET

fullName = ISNULL(@fullName,fullName),

lineShift = ISNULL(@lineShift,lineShift),

sequence = ISNULL(@sequence,sequence),

Role = ISNULL(@Role,Role),

radioChannel = ISNULL(@radioChannel,radioChannel),

officePhone = ISNULL(@officePhone,officePhone),

cellPhone = ISNULL(@cellPhone,cellPhone) 
                                                                                WHERE lineId = @lineId